# How to perform Timeseries Forecasting on dataset with repeating dates?

Tags: python, time-series, pandas

I have a dataset, I have to perform timeseries forecasting on that dataset. The dataset has date column, the dates in date column are duplicated. We have 5 classes, a date will have a sales record for each class so each date will repeat 5 times. Should I perform timeseries analysis saperately on each class or there is a way to do it directly? for clear information Check the pic below. I need to forecast sales.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you actually have 5 different time series.

Comment: @Oscar thank you. 
So I have to create 5 different datasets, each dataset for each class and then fit each dataset saperately and then finally I need to merge the results?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the forecasting model you are trying to build:

Approach 1, if you want to forecast per class individually:
create 5 different datasets, each dataset for each class and then fit each dataset separately and then merge the results

Appraoch 2, if you want one forecast of total sales amount: aggregate over (group by) class, e.g. like in this minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, '2021-01-25', 'A', 3], [1, '2021-01-25', 'B', 4]], columns=['s_no', 'date', 'class', 'sales'])
df = df.groupby('date').sum('sales').reset_index()
df
```